# What is the purpose of these PTs?

Tags: power, power-engineering

What is the purpose of these PTs installed on the two coupled busbars? And we have whole panels in the HV room for these PTs. Kindly explain. (Photo attached)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a wye primary with two wye secondaries and a open-delta secondary.

Without seeing schematics it's hard to say what each winding is used for. My guess:

- Wye 1: Metering, synchronism check.
- Wye 2: Protection.
- Open delta: for residual voltage measurement (earth fault protection) or for connection of a damping resistor to mitigate ferroresonance. Note that the screen displays "3U0" which is the residual voltage, i.e. 3 × the "zero sequence" voltage U0.

Comment: How big are these PT’s used for measurements?

Comment: Their size depends on the voltage levels (BIL), from your diagram it seems line-line voltage is 11kV. You could easily find images of that.